# Material Design EditText: OnFocusChanged stops floating hint from working properly

Tags: android

I have the following EditText:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/et_login_account_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_login_account_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/et_login_account_number"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and I want to apply an OnFocusedChangedListener to apply some validation after the user leaves the input field.

```
    et_account_number.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (InputValidator.validateEmail(et_account_number, et_account_number_wrapper, getApplicationContext()) == 1) {
                    im_account.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    im_account.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                et_account_number_wrapper.clearFocus();

            }
        }
    });
```

The above code works fine, but the problem occurs with the floating hint. The floating text no longer floats up when you select the EditText, and nor does it float down when you leave the EditText. It does however still float up when you start typing.

I guess the reason is because I am overriding the OnFocusChangedListener, thus the usual float animation doesn't play anymore since I don't specify it to do so in my Listener.

I don't know how to fix.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you not validating using addTextChangedListener? You would provide feedback while the user is typing and will not have problems with focus. Performance wise it's not going to be a problem.

Comment: @azertiti Thanks for the idea. That is a possibility but I would still like to know if it is possible to use onFocusChanged. At least now I have a backup plan.

Comment: If you really want to use the focus listener I would try adding it on TextInputLayout and see what happens. TextInputLayout certainly listens to focus changes in EditText and you are overriding the listener. I would expect it to forward to it's own listener but it's just a guess.

Comment: I have tried that but to no success. The more I'm thinking about it the more I like your first idea, think I might just go with that

Comment: Hey . got any solution ?